# TOpenFileDialog Access violation in XE6

Tags: delphi, crash, windbg, windows-7-x64, access-violation

I have a simple Delphi program with an open file dialog

```
unit Unit1;    
interface    
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation    
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  openDialog : TOpenDialog;
  i : Integer;
begin    
  openDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(self);    
  openDialog.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;    

  if not openDialog.Execute
  then ShowMessage('Open file was cancelled')
  else
  begin

  end;

  openDialog.Free;    
end;

end.
```

This seems to work ok when I click the button on the form and cancel the file open dialog.

However, after doing this, when I leave the program running 
I get an access violation.

[image: access violation]

[image: stack trace]

Could this be a bug in XE6 ?

---

**EDIT**

Just in case any of you were wondering if my windows is up to date

[image: update]

---

**EDIT**

Here is a list of the error messages I get:

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

[image: Fourth]

Comment: This is not your main thread is it? The exception seems to originate from `FunDisc.dll` wich may point to COM. What happens when you compile and run the app as a 64bit application?

Comment: Could you try to create dialog with TOpenDialog.Create(nil)?

Comment: Why do you think the exception is related to the OpenDialog?

Comment: How can we reproduce this fault?

Comment: I have just tried your code i XE6 and it worked just fine. So you have your AV some where else.

Comment: `FunDisc.dll` is related to Microsoft SkyDrive - which version of windows are you running this on? (looks like win7) Are your updates up to date?  If you have network discovery turned on, try turning it off.

Comment: possibly... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2541119  or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2494427

Comment: Voting to close this as non-repro... this seems most likely to be a windows bug, either due to neglected updates, corrupted install, virus, etc.  Either that or there is more code than is being shown.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in either XE6 or XE7, in a plain VCL forms application with a single button and the code you've included, which indicates the problem is not with that code. You need to figure out where the AV is actually coming from, because it's not there.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, When I remove the line openDialog.Execute from the program the access violation does not occur.

Comment: @J... This is all the code that I used to cause the bug, besides the .dfm code which gets auto-generated when you create a form with a button.

Comment: @MBo, the problem still occurs when I use openDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);

Comment: I've also managed to reproduce the problem while using XE5

Comment: @J... I'm using Win7 SP1

Comment: I am on a 64bit PC but I'm currently targeting 32bit.

Comment: I added an exception handler to Application.OnException  Interestingly, the application exception handler does not get triggered when the AV occurs.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers I have not been able to reproduce the problem when compiling for 64bit, or when using a 32 bit PC to target 32 bit. I think your comment is on the money.

Comment: Please don't add new findings as an answer, in stead, edit the question. Thanks for answer to my comment. New questions: 1)You said: `when I leave the program running ...`. For how long? Please try following separately. 2)What if you leave the dialog open for, say two minutes, before you cancel it? 3)What if you outcomment `openDialog.free`? Idea being the dialog spawns some processes that try to report back to a, now, non existent dialog.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, when I leave the program running it usually takes about a minute. Removing the line openDialog.Free fix the access violation.

Comment: Thank you for answers. What was the answer to my q. #2? Finally, what if you re-enable the `Free`, but change from TOpenDialog to TFileOpenDialog? (You also need to change `InitialDir` to `DefaultFolder`)

Comment: @sav We still can't see a minimal complete program. We don't have your dpr file. So we still don't know if there's a mistake in your code. Not impossible. I don't understand why you would not show an MCVE. How are you going to get to the bottom of this without one?

Comment: @sav - You can use procdump from Sysinternals to create a dump file and analyze that with windbg. My first try would be to capture first chance exceptions and unhandled exceptions using following cmdline `procdump -e 1 -n 100 Project1.exe`.

Comment: I still hear you all, thanks for sticking with me :) I'll be doing a process dump first thing Monday morning.

Comment: @sav - I thought you had left. ftr the adress `0xfeeefeee` is used by Microsoft's HeapFree() to [mark freed heap memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Another indication that it's not Delphi related.

Comment: Ok, I created a process dump using the sysinternals process explorer. This dump file does not mean anything to me though

Comment: Here's my project file http://pastebin.com/UGMG68FK

Comment: and the delphi form http://pastebin.com/1N8ZSQ6m

Comment: @sav - I can't open anything from pastebin, it will have to wait until this evening but you can start the analysis yourself and post the results here. You'll need WinDbg to open the .dmp file and run the `!analyze -v` command.

Comment: and ftr - I didn't ask about dpr/dfm/pas files, David did. I asked about the dump file. If you post the dump file somewhere or post an analysis of the dump file, I'll be happy to take a look at it *(a learning opportunity for me)*.

Comment: OK heres a zip file containing everything including dumps
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4pNQoHyyAL-bjRGaU5OcjhMSmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't make head or tail of the dumps

Comment: Do you have any exception when you run out of the debugger?

Comment: If you cant get the pastebin links, they are in the full zip file anyway

Comment: @sav - Was that comment meant for me? I don't understand that. I asked a simple question. Do you get any error dialog when you don't run your program under the debugger? To put it another way, run it outside the debugger, do you still get errors?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, sorry for the confusion. I have just tried this. There are no error messages when run outside the debugger.

Comment: @sav - Thanks. Just one more question. When run under the debugger and after you have the error, press the break button and look at the event log window. Do you see "first chance exception ..."?

Comment: You can summon the event log window with ctrl+alt+V when the IDE is active.

Comment: I have the same bug with Delphi XE5. I traced the problem to TFileOpendialog after a long time. This causes access error in even non-related functions like shellexecute/shellexecuteEx/createprocess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first ran `analyze -v` on your dump. Unfortunately and surprisingly that did not turn up anything usefull.

Next attempt was to look at all stacks using `(~*)`. This did turn up following interesting stack.

```
10 TID:1a08 kb kbn kbnL kn knL kpn kPn
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0668f128 77c7b230 ntdll!RtlLookupFunctionTable+0x85
01 0668f178 77c7b3f5 ntdll!RtlIsValidHandler+0x26
02 0668f1f8 77c30133 ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x10e
03 0668f1f8 0668f7b1 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
04 0668f6c0 77c7b499 0x668f7b1
05 0668f6e4 77c7b46b ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
06 0668f708 77c7b40e ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
07 0668f794 77c30133 ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x127
08 0668f794 7632c99e ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
09 0668fc84 76335d00 ole32!CStdMarshal::Disconnect+0x223
0a 0668fc98 76335ce1 ole32!DisconnectSwitch+0x16
0b 0668fcb0 76335d3f ole32!CStdMarshal::DisconnectAndRelease+0x44
0c 0668fe60 76368f82 ole32!COIDTable::ThreadCleanup+0xcb
0d 0668fea4 76368ec3 ole32!FinishShutdown+0x9d
0e 0668fec4 7635bac3 ole32!ApartmentUninitialize+0x96
0f 0668fedc 763688e8 ole32!wCoUninitialize+0x153
10 0668fef8 6ef2314a ole32!CoUninitialize+0x72
11 0668ff00 764943c0 NetworkItemFactory!FDBackgroundThreadHandler+0x21
12 0668ff88 7662338a shlwapi!WrapperThreadProc+0x1b5
13 0668ff94 77c59f72 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
14 0668ffd4 77c59f45 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
15 0668ffec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

At least, this confirmed our first suspicion that it is COM/system related, not Delphi. Digging into the stack looking for usefull strings turned up following string

```
d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\class\compobj.cxx
```

Now we have something new to search for: [w7rtm compobj](https://www.google.com/search?q=w7rtm%20compobj&rls=com.microsoft:nl-BE&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&gws_rd=ssl)

This lead to the following thread on SO *(notice the **identical stacktrace**)*
[Crashes in ole32!COIDTable::ThreadCleanup … NetworkItemFactory!FDBackgroundThreadHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579498/crashes-in-ole32coidtablethreadcleanup-networkitemfactoryfdbackgroundthr)

The question was asked by [Thomas W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480982/thomas-w) and commented on by [Hans Pasant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) and both are far more knowledgable using WinDbg or Windows Internals without finding a definitive solution *(at least, there's no solution posted)* so I'm afraid you are left with the following advice Hans gave to Thomas

> You are buried inside the COM plumbing with a clear hint that its
>   internal state is corrupted. This is an environmental problem, some
>   kind of DLL that gets injected into the process and screws things up.
>   Long before the crash occurs so you'll have very little hope of
>   diagnosing it with a debugger. Find the common source of the problem
>   from the modules list. Suspect any shell extension, anti-malware, any
>   utility similar to Dropbox. Use SysInternals' AutoRuns to disable
>   them. *([Hans Pasant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant))*

Assuming the fault is in a dll injected into your process, I have taken a cross section of the loaded dll's from your dump and from the application running on my computer *(it doesn't crash on my computer)* leaving following suspect dll's

```
ATL90    EhStorAPI EhStorShell  FWPUCLNT GROOVEEX_64a40000 GrooveIntlResource_63d20000 MsftEdit  OFFICE        RpcRtRemote TortoiseSVN32 TortoiseStub32
WMASF    WMVCore   WSHTCPIP     WcnApi   Wldap32           atl                         atl100    audiodev      cfgmgr32    crypt32       cryptsp
davhlpr  devobj    dnsapi       dui70    duser             fdWNet                      fundisc   gdiplus       gdiplus     ieframe       ieproxy
iertutil imm32     intl3_tsvn32 kernel32 libapr_tsvn32     libaprutil_tsvn32           libsasl32 libsvn_tsvn32 linkinfo    lpk           mpr
msasn1   msctf     msls31       msvcp100 msvcp110          msvcp90                     msvcr100  msvcr110      msvcr90     msxml6        netmsg
normaliz nsi       ntmarta      psapi    rpcrt4            secur32                     setupapi  shdocvw       shlwapi     slc           sspicli
userenv  usp10     wininet      winmm    winnsi            winsta                      wintrust  wpdshext      wpdshext    ws2_32        wship6         xmllite
api_ms_win_downlevel_advapi32_l1_1_0
api_ms_win_downlevel_normaliz_l1_1_0
api_ms_win_downlevel_shell32_l1_1_0
api_ms_win_downlevel_shlwapi_l1_1_0
api_ms_win_downlevel_shlwapi_l2_1_0
api_ms_win_downlevel_user32_l1_1_0
api_ms_win_downlevel_version_l1_1_0
```

If we leave out all Microsoft's and Unloaded dll's, following dll's remain

```
TortoiseSVN32    
TortoiseStub32   
intl3_tsvn32     
libapr_tsvn32    
libaprutil_tsvn32
libsasl32        
libsvn_tsvn32
```

So my first try on your system would be to either uninstall or disable loading of *(using autoruns)* the TortoiseSVN plugin and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: This is actually the solution! I tried uninstalling tortoise and the problem is gone. I'm impressed :)

Comment: Often I completely miss the ball but it's nice to nail it from time to time. Thanks to keep us informed.

Comment: Reading [Sertac Akyuz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28845353/52598) comments and answer, leaves me puzzled. It is correct that you shouldn't worry about the exception if it's a first chance exception but following the answer I've linked to and it having the exact same stacktrace kind of counters that?!

Comment: @Lieven - I don't think there's any contradiction, similar stack trace may not mean it should be the same error. If it would mean that, poster here should be having word, excel, firefox crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You have a "first chance exception" in ole32.dll. Not getting any errors when the program is run outside the debugger (as stated in the comments) is an indication of that. Always suspect first chance exceptions when it refers to a seemingly pseudo address, like 0xFEEEFEEE as in this case. Don't suspect for long though, check the "event log" debug window of the IDE, you should see an entry like *"First chance exception at ...."*.

A first chance exception means code has encountered an exceptional case. It doesn't mean that the exception will not be handled. That's like an exception you yourself raise in your code. For an external debugger that's a first chance exception.

There's nothing to do or worry about here. You don't have to try and avoid having the exception with workarounds or anything as long as the the program proceeds normally after that.